# iframe body remove space

Tags: html, iframe, styles, width, margin

My iframe a style of `style="width:100%"`, and it almost covers the page width. But it leaves a small margin on the left and right side. So I added `body { margin:0px; }` to remove the space.

It works, but the problem is that removing the margin on `<body>` affects other things, for example a paragraph `<p>` inside `<body>`.

Is there a way to eliminate the margin only for the `<iframe>`?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p> hello </p>
<iframe src="http://www.weather.com" style="width:100%; height:95%; margin:0px"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: nope it doesn't affect other thing. use a [css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: @lbu If I use `body { margin:0px; }`, then the paragraph `<p>` inside `<body>` also has no margin, and is right on the edge of the screen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should do some like:

```
body{margin:0} // remove body margin

iframe{margin:0;width:100%}//remove iframe margin

p,div{margin:10px} //append margin to p and other tags
```

Demo for your case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body{margin:0}
    iframe{margin:0;width:100%}
    p{margin:10px}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <p> hello </p>
    <iframe src="http://www.weather.com" style="width:100%; height:95%; margin:0px"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
As you can see, you can use body{margin:0 0 0 0px;} for top, right, bottom, left. You will be able to remove all spaces from browser.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin:0 0 0 0px;
}
</style>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.weather.com" style="width:100%; height:95%; margin:0px"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

what's wrong with:

```
iframe {
  margin: 0;
}
```

in your iframe containg page

Comment: believe me it works - if you show your code we will see if there is something elese which affects your css. This shoul be in your inframe containg page of course.

Comment: `body,iframe { margin: 0 }`,  `p { margin: 0 10px ;}` - or something like that, depending on your design requirements