# get rid of iframe body default margin

Tags: html, css, iframe, responsive-design

I'm embedding an iframe from third-party site. I have no control over it so I can't change anything inside the iframe except for width and height, which could be either absolute or percentage value.

I want the iframe contents to be resposive, so I set container's CSS width and height to 100% and iframe itself has full size div (same 100%/100%). Problem is browser adds default 8px margin to the body of the iframe, so horizontal scrollbar appears. when I disable this margin with Dev Tools it all works perfectly.

To clarify it's not the iframe margin. the inner document `body` element has a default margin of 8px set by browser.

Is there a way to get rid of that default margin? Obviously CSS has no control over iframe, I'm pretty sure JS won't work on another domain also.
it works with fixed height, e.g. I set 600 as iframe height and 616 as container's, but I want it to be changed dynamically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iframe body remove space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146177/iframe-body-remove-space)

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate. This one is about the space inside the iframe; the other is a bit unclear, but I think it's about the space outside.

Answer (score 0):

try to add `box-sizing: border-box` to the iFrame rule - this should integrate the margin into the 100%.

Comment: is it possible to set this somehow outside iframe? I have no control over it so I can't place it inside.

Comment: I meant, for the container in which you put the iframe. Or maybe also with a rule like `#container > iframe {box-sizing: border-box; }` or similar

Comment: sorry this doesn't seem to work. I tried setting it for container and iframe itself. I think the problem is with iframe contents too, it also has a 100% height div, containing SWF object.
both iframe and container have no margin, it's the inner document that has one.

Comment: one more thing you can try is `iframe body {margin: 0; }, just in case there is the usual default margin for the body in there - but I am not sure if that would work.

Comment: that's exactly my problem, the default body margin. however it doesn't seem to be possible to override it outside of the iframe

Answer (score 0):

I think this might achieve it:

`style="margin:-15px; width:calc(100% + 30px); height:calc(100% + 30px)`

The negative margin will pull the iframe to the body. Then you add in the margin to the width and heigths to extend it to the new bounds.